# Implementing a dead band selection in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, export-to-csv

I am working on a postgresql 9.3 database that basically contains timestamps and values for those timestamps. The problem is there are a lot of repeats in the data which I managed to remove using the following view. This view removes repeats, but also selects the first and last timestamp of the repeats. The 'IS NULL' comparisons selects the first and last value in the table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW viewname AS 
( SELECT timestamp, value
    FROM ( 
    SELECT timestamp,
    value, 
    lag(value) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp asc) as prevValue
    lead(value) OVER (ORDER BY timestamp asc) as nextValue
    FROM tablename) AS selectionName 
    WHERE prevValue != value OR 
    nextValue != value OR 
    prevValue IS NULL OR 
    nextValue IS NULL);
```

Now another problem arose with CSV export. To reduce the amount of data selected I must implement a dead band of 5. Meaning the next value to be selected should differ with a minimum of 5 from the previous selected value (Not just the previous value in the table). If i get values 1, 2, 4, -3, 4, 7, 8, 7, -1, the numbers I want to select are 1, (4), 7, (7), -1. The numbers in parentheses are stored too as I need to know the last value for the 'repeats'.

I have tried using pgscript to store the previously selected value as a variable and inserting into a temporary table, but storing the values twice seems redundant and is very slow when working with 15 million values.

I have also tried using various JOIN techniques, but I am unable to come up with a working solution.

It should also be noted that I cannot do this when inserting as other processes need all the values. 
Do you have any suggestions for how I can go about doing this?

EDIT: Here is a simple pgScript that fills a table with 1000 random values to get you started. It is similar enough to my actual table to be applicable:

```
CREATE TABLE deadbandtable (timestamp TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL, value smallint);

SET @max = 1000;
SET @counter = 0;
SET @v = INTEGER(0,10);

WHILE @counter < @max
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO deadbandtable (timestamp, value) VALUES(to_timestamp(@counter), @v);
    SET @counter = @counter + 1;
END
```

Comment: Edit your question, and paste CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements.

Comment: As I said in the question, the table is basically just two columns; timestamp, and value. I also stated I cannot implement dead band on the insertion as other processes need all the values. The insert statement is just timestamp and value inserted at a given intervals.

Comment: Many people who answer here have limited time. Although I could have reverse-engineered your table from the view alone, I don't really care to spend my time that way. If you provide DDL and INSERT statements, other SO users can just paste that into their own database, and more easily help you with your question.